# Compare end punctuation in columns A and B in Excel (VBA?)

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to catch and resolve instances in Excel where the end punctuation (in my case an empty line) in cells in column B doesn't match the end punctuation in cells in column A. For background, column A contains English text and column B contains translated version of the very same content. The problem is - in some cases the source text has empty/blank lines at the end of text in cells, while some translated text doesn't and I need to find and fix those instances.

So, I'm trying to:

1) Compare the last line of each cell in column A to the adjacent cell in the same row in column B.

2) If the cell in column A has a blank line at the end and corresponding cell in column B doesn't, add such blank line to the end of cell in column B.

Example:

```
         **Column A**    **Column B** 
Row 1       Text X          Text Y 
            \n
Row 2       Text X          Text Y 
Row 3       Text X          Text Y 
            \n
Row 4       Text X          Text Y 
            \n              \n
```

So, in the example above, I need to flag cells B1 and B3 because they don't have a line feed (\n) at the end, similar to their counterparts in cells A1 and A3.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would look for at whether there is a line feed in the cell and if there is it will add it to column B too.

```
Sub foo2()
FindString = "/n"
LastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'find the last row in column A with data
For i = 1 To LastRow
Set Rng = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Find(What:=FindString) 'look for the line feed at in this cell
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then 'if found
                Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value & "/n" 'add line feed to column B
            End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Or if you are not looking for the string "/n" and you are looking for the line feed then I believe something like this would do it:

```
Sub foo2()
LastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'find the last row in column A with data
For i = 1 To LastRow
Set Rng = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Find(What:= vbLf) 'look for the line feed at in this cell
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then 'if found
                Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value & vbLf 'add line feed to column B
            End If
Next i
End Sub
```

UPDATE:

```
Sub foo2()
Dim Str as Variant
    LastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'find the last row in column A with data
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        Str = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value
        If Right(Str, 1) = vbLf Then 'if found
                Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value & vbLf 'add line feed to column B
            End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: He has cells that end in `\n`, not contain just `\n`.

Comment: Correct, \n is a line feed here, it's not an actual string "\n".

Comment: @Xabier - can I maybe ask you a quick follow-up question? This works as expected, but not in cells with multiple line breaks/feeds. I only want this macro to check the last line feed (no content/characters after such line feed) and disregard any preceding ones since I have multi-line text (with line feeds separating each line) within the very same cell.

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect your comments... Now it should only look at the last line feed...

Comment: @Xabier - Thank you! I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Xabier - I'm getting an error on this when I try to run it.

**Compile error: Argument not optional**

It seems to pertain to this:
**Str =**

Comment: @BN_pdx I have now tried and tested the updated code and it works as expected, your error is because you have to declare Str as a variable, please check my updated answer once more...

Comment: @Xabier - Works perfectly, thank you very very much!

Answer (score 1):

Use column C to find line termination mismatches:

```
=(CODE(RIGHT(A1,1))=10)<>(CODE(RIGHT(B1,1))=10)
```

Copy the formula down to all rows and filter on `TRUE`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether the newline spaces are inside of the cell or lead onto the next cell I would do one of two things:

If the newline is inside of the cell, like: `CELL A1 = "Text X \n"`,
A simple solution to this could be to insert an extra column and use the `=TRIM()` formula. The `TRIM()` formula gets rid of leading and trailing spaces, you can see the Excel documentation [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TRIM-function-410388fa-c5df-49c6-b16c-9e5630b479f9)

If the newline is on the next cell, like `CELL A1 = "Text X"`, `CELL A2 = "\n"`,
Then you could just use the `LEN()` formula on the cell, and filter by "0". You can see the Excel documentation for `LEN()` [here.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LEN-LENB-functions-29236f94-cedc-429d-affd-b5e33d2c67cb)